# Add Twig global variable after kernel.request event

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am currently working on developing a project in SAAS, each client can access his platform by a personalized url (site1.com, site2.com, etc.).
For each domain name a set of template customization data is defined in the back office and I must be able to access it from my Twig files. So I defined a listener on the `kernerl.request` event that adds a global variable to Twig based on the current domain name. Everything works fine in most cases, except when a page is first displayed, Twig must be run upstream and I get the following error:

> Unable to add global "site" as the runtime or the extensions have
>   already been initialized.

*Listener class*

```
class SiteListener
{
    public function __construct(
        SiteHelper $siteHelper,
        \Twig_Environment $twig
    ) {
        $this->siteHelper = $siteHelper;
        $this->twig       = $twig;
    }

    /**
     * Add current contexts to twig global.
     */
    public function addContextsToTwigGlobal(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $this->twig->addGlobal('site', $this->siteHelper);
    }
}
```

*Listener service declaration*

```
multisite.listener.site:
        class: MultisiteBundle\Listener\SiteListener
        arguments:
            - "@multisite.helper.site"
            - "@twig"
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: addContextsToTwigGlobal }
```

*SiteHelper service*

```
class SiteHelper
{
    /**
     * @var RequestStack
     */
    protected $requestStack;

    /**
     * @var ContextConfigManager;
     */
    protected $contextConfigManager;

    /**
     * @var ContextConfig
     */
    protected $contextConfig;

    public function __construct(
        RequestStack $requestStack,
        ContextConfigManager $contextConfigManager
    ) {
        $this->requestStack         = $requestStack;
        $this->contextConfigManager = $contextConfigManager;

        $this->contextConfig = $this->contextConfigManager
            ->findByHostOrStandard($this->getHost());
    }

    /**
     * Get host from current request.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getHost()
    {
        $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();

        return ($request) ? $request->getHost() : null;
    }

    /**
     * Get current context config
     *
     * @return ContextConfig
     */
    public function getContextConfig()
    {
        return $this->contextConfig;
    }
}
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to write a [Twig function](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html) to avoid this kind of problem. This seem to be a good solution.

```
class SiteExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    /**
     * @var SiteHelper
     */
    private $siteHelper;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param SiteHelper $siteHelper
     */
    public function __construct(SiteHelper $siteHelper)
    {
        $this->siteHelper = $siteHelper;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_Function('site', array($this->siteHelper, 'getContext')),
        );
    }
}
```